# Mongoose and Next.js: Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Token')

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, mongoose-schema

I basically defined this Model, much like another which doesn't error out; So I am stumped as to why it's not working...

Here is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-ganguly-o5b3t?file=/next.config.js)

Not working:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const TokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
  token: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now, expires: 43200 }
});




export default mongoose.models.Token || mongoose.model('Token', TokenSchema);
```

Working:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import emailValidator from 'email-validator'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

import crypto from 'crypto'

const SALT_ROUNDS = 12;

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true,
      index: { unique: true },
      validate: {
        validator: emailValidator.validate,
        message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid email address!`
      }
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      index: { unique: true },
      minlength: 7,
      maxlength: 11
    },
    roles: [{ type: 'String' }],
    isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    passwordResetToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

UserSchema.pre('save', async function preSave(next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
  try {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, SALT_ROUNDS);
    user.password = hash;
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});

UserSchema.methods.generatePasswordReset = function () {
  this.resetPasswordToken = crypto
    .randomBytes(20)
    .toString('hex');
  this.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // expires in an hour
};

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function comparePassword(candidate) {
  return bcrypt.compare(candidate, this.password);
};



export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

Also I'm following this [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose) in the Next.js Examples repo.

Please help! :)

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I ran into the same one...

Comment: @andrewnosov Hey, I did—check out my repo, [here](https://github.com/antonioOrtiz/hillfinder/tree/profile-page/models) Let me know if that syntax doesn't work for you. It may be a version thing too. lmk! cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I solve my problem by moving the code of the function used directly to the request file. Don't know how this works but the problem was gone.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Token')` is happening because the code is executing on the client side when it is intended to execute on the server side.

What is really happening is that mongoose has not initiated a connection to the database, and so `mongoose.models` is undefined. But the fix isn't to try to initiate a db connection:

I too was having the a similar issue, when I tried to define too many things in the same file, that is... In my case I'm trying to define Typescript interfaces that can be pulled into client-side code, but the mongoose model definitions end up executing as well...

I read that NextJS does a fair bit of work to split up code that gets sent to client-side and what stays on server-side... The developer should keep this in mind and try to split things that relate to client-side and server-side into different files.

In my case, I placed the Interface definitions and my custom Hooks in a different file from the Mongoose Schema definitions; and then imported only the Interfaces and Hooks when I need those, which made the errors go away.

Trying to keep everything in the same place sounds logical and neat, but doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and it worked fine (went into the `tokens` collections versus `token` like expected possibly) one thing I noticed was the `expires` field on `createdAt` - was this a NextJS field? It's not a default field so just curious. Also, can you paste the exact error you are encountering, this will help someone track the issue down.

```
{
  _userId: new ObjectId("5e1a0651741b255ddda996c4"),
  token: 'abcd123',
  createdAt: 2021-09-24T23:10:24.288Z,
  _id: new ObjectId("614e5ae04c741f91ac062530"),
  __v: 0
}
```

Also, consider using the [timestamps](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) options property when declaring the model as this will save you the headache of setting `createdAt` up (and you can also have `updatedAt` automatically update).

```
    token: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  } 
);
```

Comment: So what I entered is right?

Comment: How could it be?

Comment: What error are you encountering, or do things not save? What version of mongoose do you have installed?

Comment: Well I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Token')

` and it obfuscate the UI so I can't do anything. I am using mongoose `6.0.7 `

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Even though my schema file was correct. the issue was for some reason, I have been importing the model in react component file

```
 import room from "../models/room";
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and solved with the following solution:

```
export default mongoose.models?.User || mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```